# Apple's Accelerate vDSP : How to get the argument of complex vector from FFT

Tags: ios, swift, accelerate-framework

vDSP allows computing the result of the Discrete Fourier Transform as a complex vector.

The function `vDSP_zvmags` provides the squared norm of the complex vector. How can I compute the argument (or should I do it myself by hand)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is `vDSP_zvphas`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1449904-vdsp_zvphas?language=objc

Comment: @JeremyCochoy Don't feel bad; if the documentation was better organized, it would have been linked to from vDSP_zvmags, or there would be an complete function index or something.